# XmlSerializer does not deserialize a List<string>

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlserializer

The class I'm trying to serialize and deserialize (roughly):

```
class MyDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private List<string> _uniqueNameStrings = new List<string>();

    [XmlArray("UniqueNames")]
    [XmlArrayItem("string")]
    public List<string> UniqueNameStrings 
    { 
       get => _uniqueNameStrings; 
       set => _uniqueNameStrings = value ?? new List<string>(); 
    }
}
```

Previous version without `null`-checking, not working either:

```
class MyDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("UniqueNames")]
    [XmlArrayItem("string")]
    public List<string> UniqueNameStrings { get; set; }
}
```

Schema generated for this class:

```
<xs:complexType name="MyDto">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UniqueNames" type="ArrayOfString" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfString">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="string" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

And the effect of serialization:

```
<MyDto>
    <Name>MyDtoName</Name>
    <UniqueNames>
        <string>SomeName</string>
        <string>SomeOtherName</string>
        <!-- ... <-->
    </UniqueNames>
</MyDto>
```

So serialization looks to be working properly, the problem is that when deserializing, XML seems to ignore the string values altogether. This is the calling code:

```
using System.IO.Abstractions;

private IFileSystem _fileSystem;

public void SerializeDto(object dto, string filePath)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(dto.GetType());

    using (var streamWriter = _fileSystem.FileStream.Create(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(streamWriter, dto);
        streamWriter.Flush();
    }
}

public T DeserializeDto<T>(string filePath) where T : class
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    using (var streamReader = _fileSystem.FileStream.Create(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        return (T) serializer.Deserialize(streamReader);
    }
}
```

The `Name` property (as well as all others that I have omitted for simplicity) are properly deserialized, while the `UniqueNames` are left empty. I've put a breakpoint at the `set` method and I can see that the deserializer invokes it with `value` equivalent to an empty `List<string>`, as if the `<string>` elements did not exist. Since I can't look into the XML code to see what's going on there, I'm stuck. Any ideas on why XmlSerializer ignores the values in the string array? Especially since it had itself serialized the values into this very format, and now can't handle reading it back...

Comment: If you change the element name something other than `string`, does it work?

Comment: Nope. After changing element name to `UniqueName` still `value.Count = 0`.

Comment: And if you change `UniqueNameStrings` property to `string[]` ?

Comment: It does work now, thank you! But do you have any idea why `List<string>` works one way, but not the other?

Comment: `MyDto` simply declares a list property but never creates an instance.  Somewhere an NRE is thrown.

Comment: @V0ldek I don't know, what's the framework version you are targeting?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5.1

Comment: @Plutonix Changing the implementation to be NRE safe still didn't fix the problem. I've changed the question code to reflect that.

Comment: What happens when you change your UniqueNameStrings to an auto property? (public List<string> UniqueNameStrings { get; set; }

Comment: That was the version before my code change, sorry, I should've left it for reference. Edited the question again.

Comment: How about adding [XmlRoot] to your class

Comment: Also, can you post your serialization code?

Comment: I can't reproduce this in .NET Framework 4.7 or 4.5.1, as @ParrishHusband said please add your serialization code as well.

Comment: I added the serialization code.

Comment: Can't reproduce, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/OfOPEz.  That being said, your `MyDto` must be public to be serializable at all, and your serialization code doesn't compile because `_fileSystem` is undefined and `publica` isn't a keyword.  You might have meant `public async Task` but the method doesn't contain any `await` statements and so isn't really async.

Comment: I fixed the code snippet errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class MyDto
{
    [XMLElement]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("UniqueNames"), XmlArrayItem("UniqueName")]
    public List<string> UniqueNameStrings { get; set; }

    public MyDto() { }
}
```

I can't tell from the example code, but it may be a missing empty class constructor.  Also I updated the XmlArrayItem thinking there might be a clash with calling it 'string'.

Give this Serializer a shot:

```
public static void Serialize<T>(T t, string filePath, bool overwrite = true)
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, overwrite ? FileMode.Create : FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", ""); // Omits xmlns:xsi/xmlns:xsd

        try
        {
            serializer.Serialize(fs, t, ns);
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
                File.Delete(filePath);

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. As a note - the empty ctor is there implicitly (there is no ctor specified, so an empty one is automatically generated).

Comment: @V0ldek ahh that's true on the ctor.  Grasping at straws since everything so far looks good.  Can you post your Serializing code?

Comment: I added the serialization as well.

Comment: The generic version does look better so I'm gonna keep it, but it didn't help. The output did not change, apart from the namespaces, and deserialization still gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

XML:

```
<Names>
    <Names>John</Names>
    <Names>Doe</Names>
    <Names>Martin</Names>
    <Names>Looter</Names>
</Names>
```

C#:

```
public class Configuration
{
    [XmlArray("Names")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Names")]
    public List<string> Names { get; set; }

    public Load(Stream stream) 
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Configuration));
        var config = (Configuration)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream);
        return config;
    }

}
```

use config.Names